# async function not recognized as async

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have made a function to fetch data from a server

```
const http = require('node-fetch')

getProdData = async function(prodNum) {
    const response = await http(`https://www.xxxxxx.com/api/products/${prodNum}/`)
    const json = await response.json()
    console.log(json)
    return json
}
```

if i call it directly it returns a pending promise

```
const promise = getProdData(12)
console.log(promise) // this returns a {promise:pending}
```

when i try to await it throws an error

```
const data = await promise 
// this throws [SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function]
console.log(data)
```

I've resarched into similar cases that are almost the same code and is working.

May im missing somethig?

Comment: It's as the error says - you can only `await` it if the function you're consuming the Promise in is an `async` function itself. `(async () => { const promise = getProdData(12); const data = await promise; })();`

Comment: `TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `async` functions return a promise and they return as soon as the function hits the first `await` statement.  So, the promise will always be pending right after you call the function.  If you want the value from that promise, you will have to use `await` (inside another `async` function) or use `.then()` on the promise.  Outside of the `async` function, it's really no different than regular asynchronous promise programming.

Async/await don't magically make asynchronous programming into synchronous programming.  They facilitate easier programming inside the `async` function, but outside the `async` function, it's just regular asynchronous promise programming.  Use `await` or `.then()` to get the value from the promise.

And, don't forget proper error handling with `.catch()`:

```
 const getProdData = async function(prodNum) {
    const response = await http(`https://www.xxxxxx.com/api/products/${prodNum}/`)
    const json = await response.json()
    console.log(json)
    return json
}

getProdData(someNum).then(json => {
    // use the json in here
    console.log(json);
}).catch(err => {
    // handle errors here
    console.log(err);
});
```